# Windows Authentication - How to Deny Users using Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

My Windows Authentication is working with IIS7 but now i want to deny specific users based on the data that i have in SQL server.

I know i can send a information access denied but i want to send windows login form to the user to enter different credentials, so that IIS can authenticate the new credentials and send it to the c# to authorize the user again.

Edit - To rephrase the question

I want to use both windows authentication and authentication based on database data. First i want the users to be authenticated via Windows authentication and then application will authenticate the user. But my question is if the application denies the user then I want the Windows authentication dialog box to show up to the user for windows credentials to start the process from beginning.

Comment: Did I get it right, you do not want to use Windows Authentication (domain users), but just data from a database to validate users? Or a  mixture of both?

Comment: @ Kai Hartmann I want the mixture of both. I want to validate users with Windows authentication and then i will do the authentication based on data from database but if i deny a user then i want the browser to ask for different windows credentials and process starts from beginning

Comment: Hm, this might help: http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/

Comment: @Kai I prefer not to use third party modules in authentication

Comment: I agree, I thought the article might provide some hints how to approach the issue. But I think this might help: The article in the following link describes how to use forms authentication, and impersonate a domain user on server side. The credentials of that user are checked against the windows system. So it uses forms authentication with using domain users. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2004/05/01/activate-windows-impersonation-selectively.aspx

Comment: @kai I already have that solution but i thought there will be a way just repeat the same process with different credentials . My solution now is to do the windows authentication using ldap query and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the method you can do is create your own login form and authenticate user using LDAP queries.

So initially it authenticates user via windows authentication and if other criteria doesn't satisfy the user access you can send your own login form and authenticate user using LDAP queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate by using information from a database, you would have to use forms authentication.
The steps you have to take are:

- Build a Login-Webpage (login.aspx in this example)
- Put this in your web.config, to specify the login page and deny access for all users initially:

Code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <!-- Login.aspx is the login page forms authentication should use. -->
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" >
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <!-- deny all users access to ressources of this app, if not logged in. -->
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

- In your login page, in code behind, call this to let a user pass:

Code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("UserName", False)
```

Comment: I want mixture of both